# Asp.Net application acessed from a cellphone: Open PDF file without downloading

Tags: android, asp.net, pdf, download, attachment

Good morning!

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue for some time now but couldn't make anything work, so I decided to post my question here.

So here's the context: We have a ASP.NET solution up and running online. In one of its pages, there's an option to add attachments of any kind to a certain table. Up to this moment, every time a client clicked on the "Download" button it would do just that, just download the file.

However, they've now asked that, if the file is a .pdf, for a way to not download the files but, instead, just open them directly on the browser. This wasn't an issue to implement for the browser. The issue is when they access the website on their cellphones.

Clicking the Download option on the cellphone keeps downloading the file no matter what attachment option we choose. I've seen people saying that's simply impossible to do because Android isn't prepared for that because it doesn't have the needed addons. Some people say they used iframes for this, but we don't have the file link, only their bytes.

Here's the current code:

```
string contentType = GetContentType(file_name);

Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.ToString());
Response.ContentType = contentType;
Response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
Response.End();
```

Can someone confirm that this is truly impossible to work on Android so it'll always download the file or that it's possible somehow? We've been stuck with this problem for some time and we want to know if we're trying to achieve the unachievable.

Thank you!

Comment: There are JS libraries that can embed PDF's in a webpage. Seems like that's something you should look into.

Comment: `a way to not download the files but, instead, just open them directly on the browser.` But then the browser had to download the file. And a WebView cannot display a pdf document to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You have the bytes, so convert the PDF to HTML.
If you detect a phone which might not work, give the phone the HTML.